# How to subset a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset, data-munging

I have a pandas dataframe which has 50 columns and I want to choose 30 columns.
Let's say we have the following dataframe:

```
df = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l",............, "z"]
```

I would like to choose "a" and "c" and then all the columns from "h" until "z"

Please advise on how to subset this dataframe either by name or by index.

I would like the resulting dataframe to look like the following:

```
df = ["a", "c", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l",............, "z"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) for concanecate positions of columns, then use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for selecting:

```
print (df.iloc[:, np.r_[0,2,7: len(df.columns)]])
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],
                   'b':[4,5,6],
                   'c':[7,8,9],
                   'd':[1,3,5],
                   'e':[5,3,6],
                   'f':[7,8,9],
                   'g':[1,3,5],
                   'h':[5,3,6],
                   'i':[7,8,9],
                   'j':[1,3,5],
                   'k':[5,3,6],
                   'l':[7,4,3],
                   'm':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m
0  1  4  7  1  5  7  1  5  7  1  5  7  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  8  3  3  8  3  3  4  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  9  5  6  9  5  6  3  3

print (np.r_[0,2,7: len(df.columns)])
[ 0  2  7  8  9 10 11 12]

print (df.iloc[:, np.r_[0,2,7: len(df.columns)]])
   a  c  h  i  j  k  l  m
0  1  7  5  7  1  5  7  7
1  2  8  3  8  3  3  4  4
2  3  9  6  9  5  6  3  3
```

Another solution is use `exclude list` with [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
exclude = ['b','d','e','f','g']
cols = df.columns.difference(exclude)
print (cols)
Index(['a', 'c', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm'], dtype='object')

print (df[cols])
   a  c  h  i  j  k  l  m
0  1  7  5  7  1  5  7  7
1  2  8  3  8  3  3  4  4
2  3  9  6  9  5  6  3  3
```

Or [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) columns:

```
exclude = ['b','d','e','f','g']
print (df.drop(exclude, axis=1))
   a  c  h  i  j  k  l  m
0  1  7  5  7  1  5  7  7
1  2  8  3  8  3  3  4  4
2  3  9  6  9  5  6  3  3
```

Answer (score 1):

just an extra suggestion using names:
    `df=df.loc[:, ['a','c']].join(df.loc[:, 'h':'z'])`